# Changing certain row colors based on data criteria in excel vba with 2 criteria, 1 can override the other

Tags: vba, excel

I have to levels of coloring cells here.  1st is changing rows with 0 months of stock remaining to yellow cells.  Then next is to change rows with Item status of expired, hold, or restricted.  The green overrides the yellow if the case arises.  I would like it to only color within the range of data, which is columns A-O.  I know my code isn't too far off and just needs some adjustments.  Also was wondering if just the fact that I have them listed in the correct order will produce the proper override of green over yellow.

```
    'Months of stock remaining @ <1 to yellow cell=========================

Set MoSR = Range("M7:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each Cell In MoSR
        Select Case Cell.Value
            Case Is = "<1"
                .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 10092543
        End Select
    Next

'Item status of expired,hold,and restricted to green cell==============

Set Istatus = Range("C7:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each Cell In Istatus
        Select Case Cell.Value
            Case Is = "Expired,Hold,Restricted"
                .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        End Select
    Next
```

I've edited the code to be a little more accurate

Comment: Just for your information,  you probably could do this just using conditional formatting with formulas.

Comment: I'm trying to build it in part of a macro since its part of a report that I run each week

Comment: Is the "<1" meant to be testing for `< 1` or testing for `="<1"`?  (i.e. is that cell a number, or is it a string saying "<1"?)

Comment: Anything less than 1. so from 0 to .99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Months of stock remaining @ <1 to yellow cell=========================

Set MoSR = Range("M7:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each Cell In MoSR
    Select Case Cell.Value
        'Use the next statement if the cell contains a number such as 0
        Case Is < 1
        'Use this statement if the cell actually contains a string of "<1"
        'Case Is = "<1"
            With Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":O" & Cell.Row).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 10092543
            End With
    End Select
Next

'Item status of expired,hold,and restricted to green cell==============

Set Istatus = Range("C7:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each Cell In Istatus
    Select Case Cell.Value
        Case "Expired", "Hold", "Restricted"
            With Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":O" & Cell.Row).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            End With
    End Select
Next
```

(Edited to fix the `Case` statement after I saw Thomas Inzina's answer.)